# How do I access react-navigation from inside a component that isn't the HomeScreen?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

I'm building a React Native app. I have imported createStackNavigator from react-navigation. I'm able to get it working on my Home screen - I click a button, it brings me to a new component. This is the code that I'm using to bring it into my Home.js

```
// src/components/Home/Home
export class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Button
          title="Test button"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Roads')}
        />

        <StatusBar />
        <Header />
        <Menu />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: Home,
    Roads: Roads,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
  }
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <RootStack />;
  }
}
```

My Home page takes in a Menu which has a list of MenuItems. I am trying to get the MenuItems to jump to the appropriate pages. When I try to bring in the navigation inside `MenuItem.js`'s render method, like so:

```
// src/components/Roads/Roads
  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    console.log(this.props, "props is here");
```

I get the following error message:

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')`.

Do I need to pass the navigator down in props to `Menu.js` and then to `MenuItem.js`? The docs give examples but it seems to be examples that assume you jam all your code into one file rather than across several components.

Have I set this up correctly?

Comment: Only your Screen components Home and Roads inherit the navigation prop.
This means that you will need to pass it as a prop to its children as you said:
    <Menu navigation={this.props.navigation} /> etc

Comment: This was the correct answer. Can you post it as the official answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a Navigator from react-navigation only the components you declare as Screens inherit the navigation prop (in your case Home and Roads)

This means that you will need to pass it as a prop to its children as you said:

```
<Menu navigation={this.props.navigation} />
<MenuItem navigation={this.props.navigation} />
```

In case anyone is wondering how to navigate from a component that isn't inside a Navigator then I suggest reading this part of the react-navigation documentation

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html